# Did Windows 10 just add a partition to my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I have two computers running Windows 10.  Just today, I noticed that both of them have an additional volume with a drive letter assigned to them (one of them named "Local Disk (G:)" with 68.9 free of 95.0 MB, and the other named "SYSTEM (F:)" with 70.6 MB free of 96.0 MB).  When attempting to open both of them, I receive the same error: "You have been denied permission to access this folder." Adding to the confusion, neither computer has this new volume listed in Disk Management.

Has anyone else come across this? Is it time to wipe, or is it part of a recent Windows 10 upgrade?

Comment: I've got Win10 Insider fast-ring, and I've had nothing like this.  I just have the three usual partitions; System Reserved, C: drive, and Recovery Partition.  What does diskpart tell you?

Comment: Don't wipe it, It belongs to OS. If you delete it you will face problem in your Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for the comments. DarkMoon, I checked diskpart, and I figured out the answer after doing a bit of digging:

For some reason my computers assigned a drive letter to the EFI Partition.  I ended up just unassigning a drive letter using the following commands:

```
    diskpart

    select volume=f

    remove letter=f
```

And there you have it, I cleaned up my Devices and Drives without damaging anything!

Comment: You can do that in the Partitionmanager GUI app too. Most Windows-Users seem to prefer GUI over CLI, and the diskpart CLI is horrible anyway

Answer (score -1):

The upgrade process can add a partition, and does other things.
Undoing the process, mostly, reverses them.
In many cases, simply booting to a Windows 10 install CD is enough to mess up a perfectly good Windows 7 system; so, don't do it unless your really going to upgrade to 10.  And always make backups.